# Calculate Probability of Membership from kmeans in R

Tags: r, k-means

How can I calculate the probability of membership with R's `kmeans` output?

The output of `kmeans` is as follows:

```
k <- kmeans(iris[-5], 3)
str(k)
# List of 9
# $ cluster     : int [1:150] 2 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 3 3 ...
# $ centers     : num [1:3, 1:4] 6.31 5.18 4.74 2.9 3.62 ...
# ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
# .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "1" "2" "3"
# .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width" "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"
# $ totss       : num 681
# $ withinss    : num [1:3] 118.65 6.43 17.67
# $ tot.withinss: num 143
# $ betweenss   : num 539
# $ size        : int [1:3] 96 33 21
# $ iter        : int 2
# $ ifault      : int 0
# - attr(*, "class")= chr "kmeans"
```

Is this enough information to copy what we get from `Mclust`?

```
library(mclust)
m <- Mclust(iris[-5])
head(m$z)
#           [,1]         [,2]
# [1,] 1.0000000 2.513157e-11
# [2,] 0.9999999 5.556411e-08
# [3,] 1.0000000 3.635438e-09
# [4,] 0.9999999 8.611811e-08
# [5,] 1.0000000 8.504494e-12
# [6,] 1.0000000 1.400364e-12
```

Obvious question is "Why not use `mclust`?". My data is too large to computationally do hierarchical clustering. I have tried with `Mclust`, `NbClust`, `vegan`, and many others. The call to `dist` that all of the functions use max out after a few hundred thousand rows.

I have seen some talk about probabilistic-D, and "soft" clustering, but I do not know how to implement it without changing the output of the original clusters from `kmeans`.

**Edit**
I know that SAS is able to export probabilities with `PROC FASTCLUS`, but from what I hear it is taking a sample of the data to get the probabilities. That might be one route to take if I could figure out how it's doing the subsetting.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2346069

Comment: I'll try `e1071::cmeans` based on the link, and check back, thank you

Comment: if you find something useful and are able to answer your question, I'd encourage you to post the solution as an answer to your own question. It will be helpful to others in the future